# Smuggle Probe window in burp suite is too large

Tags: windows, user-interface, burp

I'm trying to use the [HTTP Request Smuggler](https://portswigger.net/bappstore/aaaa60ef945341e8a450217a54a11646) App from the Burp Suite BApp store, but whenever I open the context menu on a request and press "Launch Smuggle Probe," I get this
[image]

The "Attack Config" window is too big, I can't move it up high enough to see the options on the bottom and I can't change the size of the window. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only solution for this is to reduce the font size under **User options** > **Display** > **User Interface**. Then restart Burp. But this will cause an unpleasant view. I'm not sure if anyone else has other workarounds for this issue.
[Reduced font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjslL.png)